# Fire a notification at a specific day and time every week

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to trigger a `UILocalNotification` every Sunday at 8PM, however, I'm having a fire date every day at 8PM.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit |   NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit| NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate: now];
    [componentsForFireDate setWeekday: 1] ; //for fixing Sunday
    [componentsForFireDate setHour: 20] ; //for fixing 8PM hour
    [componentsForFireDate setMinute:0] ;
    [componentsForFireDate setSecond:0] ;

    NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForFireDate];
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]  init] ;
    notification.fireDate = fireDateOfNotification ;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] ;
    notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"New updates!"] ;
    notification.userInfo= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New updates added for that week!"] forKey:@"new"];
    notification.repeatInterval= NSDayCalendarUnit ;
    notification.soundName=UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    NSLog(@"notification: %@",notification);//it indicates that the notif will be triggered today at 8PM and not Sunday.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification] ;
```

Thank you.

Comment: try this notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

Comment: @Chany: it jumps to the next week(next Tuesday), but not at Sunday. Here is what I have with `NSWeekCalendarUnit`: `next fire date = Tuesday, November 26, 2013 at 8:00:00 PM `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You missed the `NSWeekCalendarUnit` in the `NSDateComponents` init function.  Add the  `NSWeekCalendarUnit` to it and set the `repeatInterval` to `NSWeekCalendarUnit`, then output is

```
next fire date = Sunday, November 24, 2013 at 8:00:00 PM
```

The code is here:

```
  NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit| NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate: now];
[componentsForFireDate setWeekday: 1] ; //for fixing Sunday
[componentsForFireDate setHour: 20] ; //for fixing 8PM hour
[componentsForFireDate setMinute:0] ;
[componentsForFireDate setSecond:0] ;

  //...
  notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
  //...
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. I'll never think about it without you. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @chancyWu, I need to add one more days in week. For ex need to set monday and tuesday of every week get an local notification. What Should I do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I have also searched about it. Below code work good for me. Pass the week day value 1 to 7 Sunday to Saturday and notification body with action which you want to fire and specify your date then notification will come on that specific day.
Time will automatically set when you set date.

Hope this help you.

```
-(void) weekEndNotificationOnWeekday: (int)weekday :(UILocalNotification *)notification : (NSDate*) alramDate
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *componentsForFireDate = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit |  NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit| NSSecondCalendarUnit | NSWeekdayCalendarUnit) fromDate: alramDate];
    [componentsForFireDate setWeekday: weekday] ; //for fixing Sunday
//    [componentsForFireDate setHour: 20] ; //for fixing 8PM hour
//    [componentsForFireDate setMinute:0] ;
//    [componentsForFireDate setSecond:0] ;
    notification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
    notification.fireDate=[calendar dateFromComponents:componentsForFireDate];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Comment: What if i give [componentsForFireDate setDate: -1];  Minus one?