# iOS schedule and notifications

Tags: ios, notifications, schedule

I want to make an iOS app that checks a database every day on 10:00 AM. And if there is a new post, send a push notification, like whatsapp and facebook. I searched on Google for this but did not find anything that could help me.

Can anyone give me some information or a good tutorial about this?

Comment: Use this : http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-local-notifications/

Comment: Also Helping you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110805/fire-a-notification-at-a-specific-day-and-time-every-week

Comment: Local notifications can trigger the user to take some action, but not to have the app do some work to check a server value. The onus should be on the server to do this work and notify the app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. This should all be controlled by a server. The server should run a job at the designated time each day which checks for (unread) content and sends a push notification. The app is just there to receive the push notification and display the results.

Comment: All Right, but how could the server push the message to the app?

Comment: With a push notification - that's what they're for. The app has to register for push notifications against some notional 'account' and then you push to only devices which have registered for that 'account' when you find new content.

Comment: I found this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I am going to try this! Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about [Local & Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html). Yes, Apple documentation is very rich.

This is a cool [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6F3JaD0vdI) on how to implement it in Xcode 5.

AppCoda also has a [blog post](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/) on it.

Comment: How, specifically, can local notifications solve the described situation of checking a server at a specified time (assuming no user interaction)?

Comment: You can always code smart. Yes, Push Notifications is another option - for example Urban Airship can handle the push notifications workflow whenever there is a new WordPress blog post (just another example).

Comment: But your answer says to show a local notification. This will trigger the user to do something (if they feel like it), whether the server actually has new data or not - that app doesn't get a chance to check until the user selects the local notification and launches the app.

Comment: Depends a lot on your backend (JSON?). You can fire a local notification when the condition is true -  ```if([[self.blogDictionary objectForKey:@"BlogPostNumber"] count] > lastBlogPostNumber)``` Crude example. But, you can play around with it. Remember he has a time - 10.00 am!

Comment: So what triggers this check to run, which fires the local notification if it finds new content?