# Firing apple watch notification

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I've a todo app and I need a notification to be displayed to the watch at the scheduled todo time. How do I do this? I've read that iOS local notification automatically fires notification in the watch. Is it possible? If yes, do I need to add any code in extra to do so?

Comment: Yeah, you are correct @Naveen. "The operating system is responsible for delivering local notifications at their scheduled times; the app does not have to be running for this to happen." - [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/).
You need to add a code for Local Notifications. Get more clear for a particular ToDo from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110805/fire-a-notification-at-a-specific-day-and-time-every-week). Hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks @Rajat. Will the notification scene we've made for the watch app appear when the iPhone app fires the local notification?

Comment: Yes it will be shown on the watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In watchOS 3, you no longer need  a need to use the phone to schedule a notification.

You can now use the new [UserNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications) framework to schedule local notifications directly on the watch. These notifications will only appear on and be handled by the watch.

The WWDC 2016 [Introduction to Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/) session covers how you can use different types of triggers to fire off your todo notification, such as:

- Time interval triggers

  ```
  // In 2 minutes from now
  UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 120, repeats: false)

  // Repeat every hour starting now
  UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3600, repeats: true)
  ```
- Calendar triggers

  ```
  let dateComponents = DateComponents()
  // Configure dateComponents
  UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
  ```

The session also covers how to handle actionable notifications on the watch.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a `UILocalNotification` hasn't changed with WatchKit. The only thing that has changed is that iOS can now decide whether to send a local (or remote) notification to either the iPhone or the Watch. There is no programmatic way to control which of these devices actually displays the notification, though.

To schedule a `UILocalNotification` from a WatchKit app requires using something like the `openParentApplication:reply:` class method on `WKInterfaceController` to have the iPhone app do the actual scheduling. This is because WatchKit doesn't have access to `UIApplication`, the class that is used to schedule local notifications.

Comment: If I set the local notification in the iOS app, will the notification be displayed to the watch automatically?

Comment: Only if iOS decides to show it on the watch. Remember...you have no control over where the notification will be displayed.

Comment: the device must be locked to receive notifications in your apple watch

Comment: Or, for debugging, you can go into the Watch companion app on your iPhone and disable General/Wrist Detection.